# Странная ошибка в XAML: ошибка при конвертации типа при присваивании через StaticResource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Не знал как коротко описать суть проблемы.

Вот код xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:LocalizerLib;assembly=LocalizerLib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <loc:LocalizedString x:Key="str" OriginalString="qwe"></loc:LocalizedString>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource str}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Вот код c# класса LocalizedString

```
public class LocalizedString : IComparable, ICloneable, IEnumerable<char>, IEquatable<String>, IEquatable<LocalizedString>
{
    public LocalizedString(string str)
    {
        OriginalString = str;
    }

    public LocalizedString()
    {
        OriginalString = "";
    }

    public string OriginalString { get; set; }

    public string LocalizeString
    {
        get
        {
            return InteractiveLocalizer.Localize(OriginalString);
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return LocalizeString;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return 1;
        var str = obj as string;
        if (str != null)
            return LocalizeString.CompareTo(str);
        var lstr = obj as LocalizedString;
        if (lstr != null)
            return LocalizeString.CompareTo(lstr.LocalizeString);
        throw new ArgumentException("LocalizedDtring: Bad type");
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return new LocalizedString(OriginalString);
    }

    public IEnumerator<char> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return LocalizeString.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool Equals(string other)
    {
        return other == LocalizeString || other == OriginalString;
    }

    public bool Equals(LocalizedString other)
    {
        return OriginalString == other.OriginalString;
    }

    public static implicit operator LocalizedString(string v)
    {
        return new LocalizedString(v);
    }

    public static explicit operator String(LocalizedString ls)
    {
        return ls.LocalizeString;
    }
}
```

В данном случае LocalizedString ворачивает ту же самую строку, что и получает "qwe". Я это и ожидал, но во время выполнения прога падает с исключением. Вот текст

> "qwe" не является допустимым значением для свойства "Text".

Как так?

Ошибка есть и во время компиляции (хоть она и позволяет запуститься приложению). Вот ее текст

> Не удается применить объект типа "LocalizerLib.LocalizedString" к
>   свойству, для которого требуется тип "System.String".

В классе определены операторы implict и explict. Чего еще не хватает, чтобы я мог вместо string вставить свой тип?

Comment: Кстати, ваш подход к локализации имеет недостаток: вы не сможете сменить язык на лету (потому что `StaticResource`). А почему вы не хотите локализировать через resource dll?

Comment: @VladD, Через что локализовать? локализация на лету не очень то мне нужна, я не пишу серверное приложение. Хотя на будущее интересно было бы узнать способы локализации на лету. Мой способ локализации подразумевает локализацию пользователем. Будет написана формочка с таблицей ,в которой пользователь сам напишет перевод к нужным фразам на нужном языке. К тому же он не привязан к CultureInfo. К тому же его можно использовать не только для локализации, но и для расшифровки атрибутов XML (например оригинал - EstRowсщгте, английский - Estimate Rows Сщгте, русский - Ожидаемое количество строк) :)

Comment: @Vlad, то есть библиотека сохраняет все проходящие через нее фразы. Открывая форму для локализации, пользователь будет видеть все фразы, которые прошли через локализатор и сможет добавить к ним перевод. Само собой это не для широкого использования. Если буду использовать это для масс, то формой этой воспользуюсь сам )

Comment: Ну, мне нравится путь через `ResourceDictionary`, который кладётся в файл типа `ru-RU\assemblyname.resources.dll`. Этот файл автоматически подгружается для нужного языка (и его можно перегрузить при смене языка).

Comment: @VladD А мне не нравится. Дело в том, что я не знаю, что именно мне нужно переводить. Разбирается xml с очень большим количеством всяких тегов и атрибутов, которые должны выводиться на форму. А имена у них даже для английского кривые (сокращены). Вот я и придумал способ, прогнать все нужные мне фразы через свой класс, чтобы он их зафиксировал и сохранил в файлике, чтобы я потом мог открыть этот файлик своей программой, а там таблица для локализации, в которой уже собраны все нужные фразы.

Comment: Ну, если у вас таблица переводов динамическая, можно держать в памяти несколько ResourceDictionary, и подключать один из них (нужный). Впрочем, вы архитектор, вам и решать.

Comment: @VladD, я архитектор, а не упорный баран :). Я всегда в поиске лучшего решения. Держать в памяти несколько ResourceDictionary - это хорошо, но кто эти словари будет заполнять? :) В моем случае словари заполняет сама библиотека, а я только дописываю к фразам перевод. Я ведь оригинальные фразы вижу только при запуске приложения. А так придется вручную. Вручную шарить по XML файлу и искать все фразы. Или я не совсем понял вашу мысль. Тогда объясните подробнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XAML игноирирует операторы приведения типа (хоть явные, хоть неявные). Разнообразные конвертеры используются, например, для преобразования результатов биндинга. И даже в этом случае операторы не используются, предпочтение отдаётся ассоциированному `TypeConverter` (который, впрочем, по умолчанию поддерживает преобразование к строке и просто вызывает `ToString`). Однако при использовании ресурсов никакой конвертации не производится. Ваш код приводит к вызову:

```
object res = new LocalizedString("foo");
fooTextBlock.Text = res;
```

С очевидными последствиями.

Могу предложить несколько путей:

1. Вместо странных костылей с ресурсами можно воспользоваться расширениями разметки `MarkupExtension`. Метод `ProvideValue` может возвращать произвольный тип и даже учитывать, какому свойству какого объекта значение сейчас присваивается. Выглядеть это в XAML будет кратко и естественно:

   ```
   <TextBlock Text="{loc:Localize foo}">
   ```
2. Продолжать городить костыли, но заставить XAML вызвать конвертеры:

   ```
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource foo}}">
   ```
3. Вообще-то в WPF встроены средства для локализации, но кому до них дело...

P. S. Код не тестировал, мог наврать.

Comment: Спасибо. Штатные средства для локализации меня не устраивают. С конвертерами не все так гладко, потому что конвертер может использоваться для другой конвертации. Или есть возможность использовать несколько конвертеров по очереди? С `ProvideValue` сейчас поковыряюсь.

Comment: @iRumba Конвертер, про который вы говорите — это "пользовательский" конвертер. Биндинг после него ещё использует "системный", если тип не совпадает. См. `TypeConverter`. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Не могу найти примеров по использованию ProvideValue. Если правильно понял, в нем я просто должен вернуть конвертер (от IValueConverter). Я так и сделал, не помогает. `<TextBlock Text="{loc:LocalizeString foo}">` - вызывает ошибку

Comment: Опытным путем установил, что возвращать значение можно прямо в методе `ProvideValue`. Однако возникла беда. Во время выполнения все работает, а вот в хамле строка `<TextBlock Text="{loc:LocalizeString foo}">` подчеркивается. Ошибка доступа к файлу xml с локализацией. Можно ли как то дать доступ к этому файлу дизайнеру? Или запретить в режиме конструктора получать значения?

Comment: Аааа! Вон оно что! Текст ошибки `Отказано в доступе по пути "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\local.dat"`. У меня же путь к файлу комбинируется из названия и текущей директории. А для конструктора текущая директория - IDE ))) Что с этим можно поделать, не представляю пока.

Comment: @iRumba Никогда не используйте текущую директориию для чтения конфигов, она может меняться. Файл со строками можно добавить как Resource, Embedded Resource, Content — что больше нравится.

Comment: Я думал, что текущая директория - это место, откуда запущен exe'шник. Объясните, если не сложно. Хранить файл как ресурс - проблематично. В комментариях к вопросу я описал суть работы локализатора. Если встрою файл ка ресурс, то получу базу внутри dll, которая будет использоваться в разных приложениях. Или это работает как то иначе?

Comment: @iRumba Текущая директория — это "свойство" процесса. Задаётся при старте приложения (у ярлыка тоже есть свойство), обычно совпадает с путём к исполняемому файлу, но не обязательно. Меняется через `SetCurrentDirectory`. Диалоги открытия/сохранения могут её менять. Путь к исполняемому файлу можно брать из пути к сборке, свойства процесса или нулевого аргумента командной строки (из `Environment`). Последнее при желании тоже меняется, но риск меньше, чем у текущей директории.

Comment: Ну я брал из `CurrentDomain`. Теперь и вовсе из `Environment` подтягиваю директорию для всех пользователей. Спасибо за помощь. Есть еще вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454156/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0