# Инициализация статического класса в XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

некий статичный класс требует настройки для корректной работы. Настройку я выполняю до `InitializeComponents()`. Все выполняется хорошо, но в xamle при использовании этого класса вижу ошибки "ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта". Оно и понятно, ведь дизайнер понятия не имеет что и откуда брать. А как бы ему подсказать?

Пока обошелся тем, что проверяю статичный класс на инициализацию, прежде чем использовать. То есть в конструкторе xaml отображаются не локализованные строки

Comment: Код?​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @Discord, я думал тут есть обобщенное решение. Какой код именно интересует? Вот, например, код настройки статичного класса `InteractiveLocalizer.LocalFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "TestLocale", "local.dat");`

Comment: К слову, вы выбрали странное для файла локализации. Зачем он в AppData? Локализация обычно лежит рядом с приложением и изменению не подлежит.

Comment: @Discord, Потому что файл создается статичным классом, а если я буду класть его рядом с приложением, то конструктор (дизайнер) будет создавать еще файл рядом с запускаемым файлом студии ))))) Я и сам понимаю, что это как то не по феншую, но это лучшее, что я на данный момент придумал. в дальнейшем, скорее всего, переделаю

Answer (score 3):

Статические классы с состоянием — это **зло**. Никогда так не делайте. Ещё со школьных скамей все должны выучить, что глобальные переменные и нормальная архитектура приложения — несовместимые понятия.

1. Если ваш код не может упасть, то можно положить его в статический конструктор. Только трижды проверьте, что ваш код упасть не может. Никаких обращений к файловой системе, парсинга строк без проверок и прочего кода, который смертелен для приложения, если оказывается в статическом конструкторе. Статический конструктор никогда не должен падать. Никогда.

   ```
   <ContentControl Content="{x:Static Foo.Bar}">
   ```
2. Чуть меньшее зло — синглтоны. Лениво создайте единственный экземпляр при первом обращении к свойству. Получайте значение с помощью комбинации `Binding` и `x:Static`:

   ```
   <ContentControl Content="{Binding Bar, Source={x:Static Foo.Instance}}">
   ```
3. А ещё лучше — доверьте создание экземпляров DI. Положим, что экземпляр доступен через свойство, тогда:

   ```
   <ContentControl Content="{Binding Foo.Bar}">
   ```

Comment: К сожалению, я не знаю как обойтись без статичного класса. Я создаю экземпляр нестатичного класса `LocalizedString`. При обращении к экземпляру этого класса вызывается геттер его свойства `LocalizedString.LocalizeString`, который вызывает статичный метод `InteractiveLocalizer.Localize(OriginalString)`. Как сделать это по другому я не знаю.

Comment: @iRumba Чем вас синглтон не устроил?

Comment: А чем он в данном случае выгоднее в плане защиты от падений?

Comment: @iRumba Тем, что в случае ошибки у вас просто не загрузится окошко, а в случае падения статического конструктора у вас всё приложение придёт в негодность, причём, возможно, до выполнения всяких `Main`.

Comment: Ну так проблемных мест там очень мало (в моем случае два) и их вполне можно обернуть в `try..catch`. В конечном счете тщательная обработка класса упрощает его использование в дальнейшем. Слишком длинные строки и состоящая из многих элементов логика при использовании только мешается. В идеале я хочу написать `Перевести("String for localizable")` и получить "Строка для перевода". К такому идеалу и стремлюсь. Мне проще преодолеть сложности при описании класса.